# Include both short and long caption in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, subfloats, tocloft

I'm writing a paper where I'm trying to repurpose the list of figures as a figure legends section. I'd like each figure to have something like "Figure X: Title" at the bottom, with list of figures entries containing "Figure X: Title", followed by the legend on a new line.

I've almost got what I want using the tocloft package with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\addtocontents{lof}{\cftpagenumbersoff{figure}}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{Figure Legends}
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{\bfseries Figure }
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{\bfseries :}
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnumb{\\}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\setlength\cftbeforefigskip{12pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering \includegraphics{image1}
  \caption[Normally a much longer legend for the first figure.]{Title for first fig}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]

\clearpage
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Note that I've put the legend in the "short" caption and the title in the "long" caption. The one thing I haven't managed to figure out is how to have both the "short" and "long" captions in the list of figures.

I considered using the cftXaftersnum command to include the short caption as a variable, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

UPDATE:

The answer is brilliant, but I neglected to point out one additional requirement: I need doublecaption to cooperate with subfigures. I have one figure with two subfigures, and the counter gets double-incremented. Here's an example using the solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\addtocontents{lof}{\cftpagenumbersoff{figure}}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{Figure Legends}
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{\bfseries Figure }
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{\bfseries : }
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\setlength\cftbeforefigskip{12pt}

\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{\cftfigpresnum}
\addtolength\cftfignumwidth{\mylength}

\makeatletter
\def\doublecaption{%
  \ifx\@captype\@undefined
    \@latex@error{\noexpand\caption outside float}\@ehd
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \refstepcounter\@captype
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\@dblarg{\@doublecaption\@captype}}%
}
\long\def\@doublecaption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3\newline#2}}%
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering \includegraphics{image1}
  \doublecaption[Normally a much longer legend for the first figure.]{Title for first fig}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering 
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{image2}   
    \caption{Case one}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{image3} 
    \caption{Case two}
  \end{subfigure}
  \doublecaption[Not very long legend for fig with subfigs.]{Title for fig with subfigs}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]

\clearpage
\listoffigures


\end{document}
```

I can see in the doublecaption definition that the counter is incremented by:

```
\refstepcounter\@captype
```

I guess the subcaption package must do something to prevent double-incrementing counters, but I'm not sure how to do this. I can always just explicitly decrement the list counter after the subfigures, but before the figure's doublecaption, but I suspect there's a better way?

Comment: Although you're a member since 7 months, this is your first question, so: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a way. Let's define a new command `\doublecaption` to be used when you want that behavior in the LoF:

```
\makeatletter
\def\doublecaption{%
   \ifx\@captype\@undefined
     \@latex@error{\noexpand\caption outside float}\@ehd
     \expandafter\@gobble
   \else
     \refstepcounter\@captype
     \expandafter\@firstofone
   \fi
   {\@dblarg{\@doublecaption\@captype}}%
}
\long\def\@doublecaption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3\newline#2}}%
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

The definition is taken from the normal `\caption` and modified to fit your needs.

In the `tocloft` settings, remove

```
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnumb{\\}
```

and add

```
\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{\cftfigpresnum}
\addtolength\cftfignumwidth{\mylength}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\addtocontents{lof}{\cftpagenumbersoff{figure}}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{Figure Legends}
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{\bfseries Figure }
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{\bfseries :}
%\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnumb{\\}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\setlength\cftbeforefigskip{12pt}

\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{\cftfigpresnum}
\addtolength\cftfignumwidth{\mylength}

\makeatletter
\def\doublecaption{%
   \ifx\@captype\@undefined
     \@latex@error{\noexpand\caption outside float}\@ehd
     \expandafter\@gobble
   \else
     \refstepcounter\@captype
     \expandafter\@firstofone
   \fi
   {\@dblarg{\@doublecaption\@captype}}%
}
\long\def\@doublecaption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3\newline#2}}%
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering \includegraphics{image1}
  \doublecaption[Normally a much longer legend for the first figure.]{Title for first fig}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering \includegraphics{image2}
  \caption{Title for second fig}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

Please next time, post examples with all relevant loaded packages...

To let it work with `subcaption`, we'll define two commands:

1. `\doublecaption`, to be used in figures with no subfigures.
2. `\doublesubcaption`, to be used in figures with subfigures.

Substitute the above code starting with `\makeatletter` and ending with `\makeatother` with this one (require the `etoolbox` package):

```
\makeatletter
\let\doublecaption\caption%
\patchcmd{\doublecaption}%
  {\@caption}%
  {\@doublecaption}%
  {}%
  {}%
\let\@doublecaption\@caption%
\patchcmd{\@doublecaption}%
  {\addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}}%
  {\addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3\newline#2}}}%
  {}%
  {}%
\let\doublesubcaption\doublecaption%
\patchcmd{\doublesubcaption}%
  {\refstepcounter\@captype}%
  {\relax}%
  {}%
  {}%
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\addtocontents{lof}{\cftpagenumbersoff{figure}}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{Figure Legends}
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{\bfseries Figure }
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{\bfseries : }
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\setlength\cftbeforefigskip{12pt}

\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{\cftfigpresnum}
\addtolength\cftfignumwidth{\mylength}

\makeatletter
\let\doublecaption\caption%
\patchcmd{\doublecaption}%
  {\@caption}%
  {\@doublecaption}%
  {}%
  {}%
\let\@doublecaption\@caption%
\patchcmd{\@doublecaption}%
  {\addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}}%
  {\addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3\newline#2}}}%
  {}%
  {}%
\let\doublesubcaption\doublecaption%
\patchcmd{\doublesubcaption}%
  {\refstepcounter\@captype}%
  {\relax}%
  {}%
  {}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering \includegraphics{image1}
  \doublecaption[Normally a much longer legend for the first figure.]{Title for first fig}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{image2}
    \caption{Case one}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{image3}
    \caption{Case two}
  \end{subfigure}
  \doublesubcaption[Not very long legend for fig with subfigs.]{Title for fig with subfigs}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]

\clearpage
\listoffigures


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I don't quite understand everything you've done yet, but that's great!

Comment: I've got an additional request: How can I make this cooperate with subcaption (for figure numbering)? See above.

Comment: @rainbowgoblin See the edit (and remember that you can also upvote the answer, if you want).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise I had enough points to upvote :)